# Using a variable for a date range in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I alter the code below to get a date range as opposed to one day? Code 1 works, code 2 doesn't (I'm using Oracle SQl Developer)

**CODE 1**

```
DEFINE date1 = '01-JUN-17' 
SELECT * 
FROM   op_all_appointments OP 
WHERE  OP.ATTENDANCE_DTTM = '&&date1'
```

I tried the below, but it doesn't work? It returns data for the 1st June 2017 only

**CODE 2**

```
DEFINE date1 between '01-JAN-17' and '30-JUN-17'
SELECT * 
FROM   op_all_appointments OP 
WHERE  OP.ATTENDANCE_DTTM = '&&date1'
```

Thank you

Comment: What are you even trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to work out how to use a variable to get a date range in Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: Wouldn't you want 2 variables? 1 for each start and end date?

Comment: Using two variables worked. Thank you. Is there a way to do it with one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you looked at the output you got carefully, for your second `define` you would see:

```
SP2-0135: symbol date1 between '01-jan-17' and '30-jun-17' is UNDEFINED
```

so that command isn't actioned, your first define is still in effect, and you therefore still see the data for your first single date.

You could do it one go with:

```
DEFINE date1 = between '01-JAN-17' and '30-JUN-17'
```

which adds in the missing `=` which caused that SP error; your query woudl then change to:

```
...
WHERE  OP.ATTENDANCE_DTTM = &&date1
```

*without* an equals sign, and without quotes around the substitution variable.

But as this is relying on implicit conversion and your NLS settings, really you would need to do:

```
DEFINE date1 = between to_date('01-JAN-17', 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''ENGLISH''') and to_date('30-JUN-17', 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''ENGLISH''')
```

or more simply using date literals:

```
DEFINE date1 = between date '2017-01-01' and date '2017-06-30'
```

It would probably be neater to use two variables:

```
DEFINE date1 = 2017-01-01
DEFINE date2 = 2017-06-30

...
WHERE  OP.ATTENDANCE_DTTM between date '&&date1' and date '&&date2'
```

It's also worth noting that if your column has times other than midnight - as the `DTTM` suggests - you will miss any data on the last day of the range, i.e. anything after midnight on 2017-06-30. It's generally safer with a range to do:

```
DEFINE date1 = 2017-01-01
DEFINE date2 = 2017-07-01

...
WHERE  OP.ATTENDANCE_DTTM >= date '&&date1'
AND    OP.ATTENDANCE_DTTM < date '&&date2'
```

and you could the same range comparison in a single substitution variable if you really wanted to.

You might also want to consider using bind variables instead of substitution  variables - though then you can't use date literals, but should still stick to a language-independent format and use `to_date()` with an explicit format mask; e.g.:

```
var date1 varchar2(10);
var date2 varchar2(10);
exec :date1 := '2017-01-01';
exec :date2 := '2017-07-01';

...
WHERE  OP.ATTENDANCE_DTTM >= to_date(:date1, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
AND    OP.ATTENDANCE_DTTM < to_date(:date2, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

... which you can't do in a single variable (with plain SQL anyway).

Comment: Hi Alex, i can't thank you enough for the help with the intuition. Your answer (DEFINE date1 = between '01-JAN-17' and '30-JUN-17') worked for me. Great stuff

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should be doing

```
SELECT * 
FROM   op_all_appointments OP 
WHERE  OP.ATTENDANCE_DTTM between date '2017-01-01' and date '2017-06-30'
```

If you want to use CTE

```
WITH data AS
    (SELECT DATE '2017-01-01' date1,
            DATE '2017-06-30' date2
    FROM dual
    )
SELECT *
FROM dual,
    data
WHERE sysdate BETWEEN data.date1 AND data.date2;
```

Comment: Thank you Sudipta, but it's not what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: your options are to use two variables or use CTE or PLSQL Record types. But I am not sure, you will want to use PLSQL.

Answer (score -1):

```
DEFINE date1 = 'between ''01-JAN-17'' and ''30-JUN-17'''
SELECT * 
FROM   op_all_appointments OP 
WHERE  OP.ATTENDANCE_DTTM  '&&date1'
```

OR (try both)

```
DEFINE date1 = 'between ''01-JAN-17'' and ''30-JUN-17'''
SELECT * 
FROM   op_all_appointments OP 
WHERE  OP.ATTENDANCE_DTTM  &&date1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, this didn't work:ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
00920. 00000 -  "invalid relational operator"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 28

Comment: Thank you Sergiu, the second code worked for me. Much appreciated